# Computer screen turned white on start up

Tags: laptop

I have HP ProBook 4330s.One day the screen just turned white and I was advised that it was the video cable so I bought a new one and inserted but the problem is still on. When I connect the laptop to an external monitor via VGA it just works fine. I have also tested my laptop screen in another working laptop and the screen is also fine. Am stuck with options here please anybody with a clue of what is wrong with my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what you changed?

In my experience there should be a cable that goes from the LCD to an inverter board, an inverter board, and a cable that goes from the inverter board to the motherboard.

If the inverterboard is damaged or not working properly I usually see strange colors- doesn't just go all white so I don't think that's the issue.

I would guess most likely it's the ribbon cable form the motherboard to the inverter board.

It's possible the output on the motherboard has failed... so provided you're confident in the cabling to the LCD I would replace the motherboard.

Comment: HiThe cable that I replaced is the one running from the motherboard to the back of the LCD. It doesn't have the cable for the inverter board